# Execute Javascript function when muoseover on option in Chosen JQuery Combobox

Tags: javascript, jquery, combobox, jquery-chosen

I wanted to ask if it was possible to run a javascript when mouseover on single options in [Chosen](https://github.com/harvesthq/chosen) JQuery Combobox

For example:

```
  $('#comboCMBGROUP').bind(' onMouseOver, function () {
      var Value1 = $(this).val();
      alert(Value1);   
  });
```

I have use this but the javascript don’t run. There is a solution?
In a normal combobox html i have use this code but a want run it on Chosen Combobox:

Example:

```
<select style='width:180px; cursor:pointer;' id='comboCMBGROUP' data-placeholder='' class='chosen-single'>
<option onMouseOver="javascript:alert('1');">1</option>
<option onMouseOver="javascript:alert('2');">2</option>
<option onMouseOver="javascript:alert('3');">3</option>
</select>
```

Comment: Since chosen hides the select and adds `ul li`, you will have to bind the mouseover for the `lis`.

Comment: do you can post me an example?

Answer (score 0):

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#selectBox').chosen();

  $(document).on('mouseover', '#selectBox + .chosen-container .chosen-results li', function() {
    $('p strong').html($(this).text()).css({
      'color': $(this).text()
    });

  });
});
```

```css
select {
  width: 100px
}
p {
  text-align: center
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<script src="http://harvesthq.github.io/chosen/chosen.jquery.js"></script>
<link href="http://harvesthq.github.io/chosen/chosen.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<select id="selectBox">
  <option value="red">red</option>
  <option value="green">green</option>
  <option value="blue">blue</option>
</select>
<p>Hovered value: <strong></strong>
</p>
```

Answer (score 0):

if i use your code when i move mouso on all object show message

in  i have this:

```
<link rel='stylesheet' type='text/css' href='css/chosen.css'>
```

in  i have this:

```
<div id='comboCMBGROUP_container' class='ComboTextCont_Small' style='left:6px; margin-top:6px; z-index:9999;'>
<select style='width:180px; cursor:pointer;' id='comboCMBGROUP' data-placeholder='' class='chosen-single'>
<option value='1'>GRUPPO_1</option>
<option value='2'>GRUPPO_2</option>
<option value='3'>GRUPPO_3</option>
</select>
</div>
```

and at and of html code i have:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="script/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="script/chosen.jquery.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">
    var config = { 
      '.chosen-single'  : {disable_search:true},
      '.chosen-select-deselect'  : {allow_single_deselect:true},
      '.chosen-select-deselect': {no_results_text:'Nessun risultato!'},
      '.chosen-select-no-results': {no_results_text:'Nessun risultato!'},
      '.chosen-select-deselect': {disable_search:false},
      '.chosen-select-deselect': {enable_split_word_search:true},
      '.chosen-select-deselect': {search_contains:true}
    }
    for (var selector in config) {
      $(selector).chosen(config[selector]);

      $('.chosen-drop').css('white-space','nowrap');
      $('.chosen-drop').css('min-width','180px');
      $('.chosen-drop').css('width','auto');
      $('.chosen-results').css('padding','0 10px 0 0');
    }
</script>

<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
/*jQuery time*/


  $('#comboCMBGROUP').chosen();

  $('#comboCMBGROUP_container').bind('mouseover', '#comboCMBGROUP + .chosen-container .chosen-results li', function() {
    var value1 = $(this).val();
    alert(value1);      

  });


});</script>
```

if i use your code:

```
  $('#selectBox').chosen();

      $(document).on('mouseover', '#comboCMBGROUP + .chosen-container .chosen-results li', function() {
                var value1 = $(this).val();
    alert(value1);  

      });
```

i recive response on any objet not only when i move on option '#comboCMBGROUP'

if i use:

```
  $(#comboCMBGROUP_container).bind('mouseover', '#comboCMBGROUP + .chosen-container .chosen-results li', function() {
            var value1 = $(this).val();
    alert(value1);  

  });
```

i recive recive response only on '#comboCMBGROUP_container' the value is null, and show when the mouse enter on div, but i what to sho only when i enter on option of combo

Comment: You can edit your question and add the above things. Can you tell me what version of jquery you are using?

Comment: Hi ok I have update the jquery and now your code run perfect.  I want to read the value of option an no the text.  If I write $(this).val();  di 't receive the value assigned to option.  Why?   Thanks for help me.

Comment: Mouseover won't give the value as nothing is selected. You need to add another event on change and get the value. [Check this link](http://harvesthq.github.io/chosen/options.html#triggered-events)

Comment: Sorry, but it would be possible to derive the value of going to search for in the document $ (this) .text () if this was unique within the combo box?

Comment: Why do you need to do the checking? If you look at the examples here [Chosen](http://harvesthq.github.io/chosen/) and start typing locations which doesn't match the combobox, automatically it says `no results match "text"`

Comment: I would hover over the options to run a javascript that according to the parameters set as the value of the option to show thumbnails